# how to migrate from xampp to appserv?

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I have this codeigniter project that was developed and tested on xampp, when the customer took xampp wouldn't work on his laptop, so he downloaded the appserv and wants to use it instead of the xampp, the home page of the login page of the system is displayed fine but he vannot log in, I changed the database sittings in the database.php file in the codeigniter project, and also removed the comment before rewrite role in the httpd.conf but yet its not working
any help please

Answer (score 0):

set the CI environment to development in your index.php and error_reporting to E_ALL and see what's going wrong. If it's the database, or sessions, browser may have not accepting cookies etc.

Ok, you have probably a base path issue. check $config["base_path"] in application/config/config.php and set it to the directory name relative to web server root.

Like XAMMP has usually

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\
```

and the project url might be

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\projects\project_a
```

then your base_path would be

$config["base_path"] = "procjects\project_a";

Comment: It gives in the firefox console "404" not found, it cannot see the controller

Comment: I have this in my url_bath
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

Should I change something in it???

Comment: what's your site's local url? where's your index.php located?

Answer (score 0):

In database.php, please make sure that you have to enter the password as you setup while installing appserv.[copy the password that you entered in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swaM0.gif)

```
$config['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['username'] = 'root';
$config['password'] = 'your_password';
$config['database'] = 'your_database';
$config['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$config['dbprefix'] = '';
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = '';
$config['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$config['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

replace "your_password" with copied password from the above and check it.

otherwise, On the left end of the taskbar, select the Start  icon and search for "Reset MySQL Root Password" click on it to open.

In the command window,  Please enter the NEW_PASSWORD and Replace it in your database.php